# What's wrong with my regex to validate a pattern in my html input?

Tags: html, regex

I have an input box on my site and I want to validate that it is between 4 and 30 characters that are alphanumeric or any of . _ - (dot, underscore, hyphen).

e.g. these are valid:

- hello-
- goodbye23_.sd

not valid:

- boo
- nospecials%
- this has a space

In my html I have this line:

```
<input id="handletext" type="text" spellcheck="false" pattern="^[\w-\.]{4,30}$" maxlength="30" />
```

I get an error in the debugger when I load the page in latest Chrome:

> Pattern attribute value ^[\w-.]{4,30}$ is not a valid regular
>   expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
>   /^[\w-.]{4,30}$/: Invalid character class.

Any ideas what's wrong with my pattern?

Comment: @Ehssan that's what I have.

Comment: You must escape the hyphen or put it at the start/end of the character class and remove escaping backslash from `.`: `pattern="[\w.-]{4,30}"`. You do not need `^` and `$`, the anchors are added automatically by the HTML5 engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*2023 Update**

Now, escape the hyphen inside character classes even at the end of it:

```
pattern="[\w.\-]{4,30}"
```

**Original answer**

You must escape the hyphen or put it at the start/end of the character class and you also need to remove escaping backslash from `.`. As `.` is not a special char inside a character class, it should not be escaped in a pattern that is compiled with `u` modifier (and it is compiled with that flag in most browsers, Chrome included).

Use

```
pattern="[\w.-]{4,30}"
```

Note that you do not need `^` and `$`, the anchors are [added automatically by the HTML5 engine](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute).

In Chorme, the pattern will be compiled as `/^(?:[\w.-]{4,30})$/u` regex and will match a string that consists of four to thirty ASCII letters, digits, `_`, `.` or `-` chars.

Comment: How is the underscore matched?

Comment: Underscore is part of \w (I don't know why, but it is)

Comment: @MarkAllison `\w` in JS is a shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If you do not want to match it, use `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{4,30}"`

Comment: regarding the "2023 update" -- is there a reference to when the dash at the end of a character class started to require an escape? this didn't used to be necessary.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer I tried to go through all my "HTML5" tagged answers and add that information, but I would need much more time :) [Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76287241/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

`pattern="[\w\-\.]{4,30}"` works for me, so you also may try it.

The point here is that you must escape the hyphen.